# DeepMerge<> generic not supporting deep optional

Tags: typescript

I have a `DeepMerge<>` generic below that is not supporting deep optional merges.

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U;
```

I have a `Person` with a deep optional `address`.

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: {
    line1: string,
    line2: string | null | number,
    zip: string | number,
    address?: {
      line1: string,
      line2: string | null | number,
      zip: string | number,
    },
  },
};
```

I want to overwrite the deep `address` and add `burger`.

```
type PersonOverwrites = {
  address: {
    pizzaDelivery: boolean,
    address?: {
      burger: boolean,
    },
  },
};
```

Here is is complaining:

```
const person: DeepMerge<Person, PersonOverwrites> = {
  name: 'Thomas',
  age: 12,
  address: {
    line1: 'hi',
    line2: 'hi',
    zip: 'hi',
    pizzaDelivery: true,
    address: {
      line1: 'hi',
      line2: 'hi',
      zip: 'hi',
      burger: true,
    },
  },
};
```

It should require `line1`, `line2`, `zip`, `burger`.

[image]

> Type '{ line1: string; line2: string; zip: string; burger: true; }' is not assignable to type '{ burger: boolean; }'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'line1' does not exist in type '{ burger: boolean; }'.

It should be supporting `{ line1: string; line2: string; zip: string; burger: true; }` but instead the entire deep object is being overwritten to `{ burger: boolean; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I think the problem here is that `keyof ({a: string} | undefined)` is showing up as `never` so as soon as the property is optional, `DeepMerge` can't recurse any farther down.  There are probably other ways to fix this, but for a first shot, how about changing `T` and `U` to `NonNullable` versions of themselves, where `NonNullable` is [defined in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1466-L1469) as

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Let's try it:

```
type DeepMerge<_T, _U, T= NonNullable<_T>, U= NonNullable<_U>> =
  [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U;
```

Does that work?  That infers the type of `person` as

```
const person: {
    address: {
        pizzaDelivery: boolean;
        address?: {
            burger: boolean;
            line1: string;
            line2: string | number | null;
            zip: string | number;
        } | undefined;
        line1: string;
        line2: string | number | null;
        zip: string | number;
    };
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

---

EDIT: it's also possible that all you want is to [distribute across all unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types), like this:

```
type DeepMerge<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends any ?
  [T, U] extends [object, object] ?
  {
    [K in keyof (U & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>)]: (
      K extends keyof U ? (
        K extends keyof T ? DeepMerge<T[K], U[K]> : U[K]
      ) : (
        K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
      )
    )
  } : U : never : never;
```

Maybe that works better for you?

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Just to play devils advocate here, this will not deal well with unions: `type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  address: { other: string} | { /* same as before */  } }`

Comment: yeah, unions are an issue... not sure if they want distributive unions or what.

Comment: If so, then you should specify what you want to see with unions.  An example like `type E = DeepMerge<A | B, C | D>` with some concrete `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and the desired output `E` would be a good start.  Updated answer with possible solution for unions, but not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: The issue with this latest update is that it allows for both of these objects as a union I just want to support the later of the two objects. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGo1o.png

Comment: What I am really trying to do is merge objects and the `B` limits the original union set. That's it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  I think I need you to go through the exercise of explicitly giving some concrete examples with unions and what you want to see exactly.